# Updating a button's text from a function being run on interval isn't working

Tags: javascript

I'm teaching myself JavaScript and am going through some various examples.  One thing I wanted to do was make a button count down from 10 to 0 when clicked, so I could demonstrate the use of the setInterval and clearInterval methods.

From logging to console, everything looks to be running as I expected, but the text on the button is not updating.

Here's how the button is defined...

```
<!-- Example 6 -->
  <tr>  
   <td><h2>Example 6: Timing</h2></td>
  <tr>
   <td>Click the button to start the countdown</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><button id="example6Button" onclick="example6Click()">Start Countdown</button></td>
  </tr>
```

When the button is clicked, it's supposed to change the button text to 10, and every second change the text to 9, 8, 7, etc. until it gets to 0.

Here's the two functions involved.  The button click fires example6Click() and that function uses setInterval to fire example6Count() every second.

```
  var example6Counter = 10;
  var example6Timer;

  function example6Click()
  {
    console.log("example6Click() called");
    example6Timer = setInterval(function(){example6Count()}, 1000);       
  }

  function example6Count()
  {
    console.log("example6Count called");
    console.log("example6Counter = " + example6Counter);

    var btn = document.getElementById("example6Button");
    console.log("btn = " + btn.id);

    var outMsg = "Count = " + example6Counter;
    console.log("outMsg = " + outMsg);

    btn.value = outMsg;
    console.log("btn.value = " + btn.value);

    example6Counter--;

    if(example6Counter <= 0)
    {
      console.log("calling clearInterval");
      clearInterval(example6Timer);
    }
  }
```

Here's the Console output I get when testing in Chrome.  It shows that the `example6Click()` function is called, and then the `example6Count()` function is called once per second as I would expect.  It shows the button is being found when I call `getElementById`, and it shows after I've set `btn.value = outMsg` that the btn.value is set correctly.

```
example6Click() called jsdemo.html:128
example6Count called jsdemo.html:134
example6Counter = 10 jsdemo.html:135
btn = example6Button jsdemo.html:138
outMsg = Count = 10 jsdemo.html:141
btn.value = Count = 10 jsdemo.html:144
example6Count called jsdemo.html:134
example6Counter = 9 jsdemo.html:135
btn = example6Button jsdemo.html:138
outMsg = Count = 9 jsdemo.html:141
btn.value = Count = 9 jsdemo.html:144
example6Count called jsdemo.html:134
example6Counter = 8 jsdemo.html:135
btn = example6Button jsdemo.html:138
outMsg = Count = 8 jsdemo.html:141
btn.value = Count = 8 jsdemo.html:144
example6Count called jsdemo.html:134
example6Counter = 7 jsdemo.html:135
btn = example6Button jsdemo.html:138
outMsg = Count = 7 jsdemo.html:141
btn.value = Count = 7 jsdemo.html:144
example6Count called jsdemo.html:134
example6Counter = 6 jsdemo.html:135
btn = example6Button jsdemo.html:138
outMsg = Count = 6 jsdemo.html:141
btn.value = Count = 6 jsdemo.html:144
example6Count called jsdemo.html:134
example6Counter = 5 jsdemo.html:135
btn = example6Button jsdemo.html:138
outMsg = Count = 5 jsdemo.html:141
btn.value = Count = 5 jsdemo.html:144
example6Count called jsdemo.html:134
example6Counter = 4 jsdemo.html:135
btn = example6Button jsdemo.html:138
outMsg = Count = 4 jsdemo.html:141
btn.value = Count = 4 jsdemo.html:144
example6Count called jsdemo.html:134
example6Counter = 3 jsdemo.html:135
btn = example6Button jsdemo.html:138
outMsg = Count = 3 jsdemo.html:141
btn.value = Count = 3 jsdemo.html:144
example6Count called jsdemo.html:134
example6Counter = 2 jsdemo.html:135
btn = example6Button jsdemo.html:138
outMsg = Count = 2 jsdemo.html:141
btn.value = Count = 2 jsdemo.html:144
example6Count called jsdemo.html:134
example6Counter = 1 jsdemo.html:135
btn = example6Button jsdemo.html:138
outMsg = Count = 1 jsdemo.html:141
btn.value = Count = 1 jsdemo.html:144
calling clearInterval
```

However, the text on the button still isn't changing.  Why?  I also tried `btn.innerHTML = outMsg` but that doesn't do any good.  I also tried having a separate label or span to set the countdown text but those weren't working either.

Is the `example6Count()` function being called in a separate thread that can't update the UI or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to disagree with jp310 and tell you to use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent), as you're not sticking HTML in, just text:

```
btn.textContent = outMsg;
```

Another tweak: You're being a bit redundant in your `setInterval`, as it can be slimmed down to:

```
example6Timer = setInterval(example6Count, 1000);
```

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z4Pd4/1/) for a working example.

Comment: I think innerText is the same as well.

Comment: @jp310 Not so - `textContent` won't cause a repaint and helps avoid thrashing.  http://www.kellegous.com/j/2013/02/27/innertext-vs-textcontent/

Comment: Using textContent worked for me.  I don't know why it doesn't work with innerHTML; I expected it to.

Comment: @Jim Awesome, glad I could help.  Don't forget to upvote/accept, and welcome to the wild world of JavaScript!

Comment: I especially appreciate the JSFiddle link.  I knew there was an SQL Fiddle but didn't know the same existed for JS.

Answer (score 1):

Use innerHTML instead of value.

```
btn.innerHTML = ...
```

Because you are using a `<button>` instead of `<input type="button">`, you need to set the innerHTML. `<button>`s do not take their text based on the value attribute.

Comment: I already tried using innerHTML.  My OP says that.  Same results.

Comment: http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/jquery-set-innertext-2/       How about innerText?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
btn.value = outMsg;
```

with

```
btn.innerHTML = outMsg;
```